# Trying to Update a table while using a left join in MySQL gives Syntax Error

Tags: mysql, syntax, sql-update, left-join

I am trying to update a table in my MySQL database but it gives an error and i am out of ideas on how to fix it. Maybe someone can point me in the right direction or tell me what i am doing wrong.

My code:

```
UPDATE creature_template ct 
LEFT JOIN creature c ON ct.Entry = c.id 
SET ct.MinLevelHealth=MinLevelHealth / 5 
WHERE creature.map = '565';
```

The error:

> 1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'WHERE creature.map='565'' at line 4

Thank you!

Comment: Note that you dont need to use `LEFT JOIN`, as you are filtering on the right-side table. You can simply use `INNER JOIN` instead, as it would be more performant.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this

```
SET ct.MinLevelHealth=(MinLevelHealth / 5 )
```

Instead Of

```
SET ct.MinLevelHealth=MinLevelHealth / 5
```

Comment: That worked, thank you! I thought the error was located in the WHERE clause due to the error message ...